# How to use React useCallback and useEffect with outside dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to follow react-plugin-react-hooks.

I have a `useEffect` which adds an event listener to the `window` (`onScroll`). `onScroll` makes use of `window.pageYOffset`.

```
function onScroll() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 0) {
      setFoor(bar)
    } else {
      setFoor(baz)
    }
  }
```

Now in the `useEffect` I have:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    onScroll();
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    };
  }, []);
```

This was following the idea initially supported recommendation that if you pass an empty dependency array, it's like `componentDidMount`. But the React docs clearly say that you should either pass no dependencies (not even empty array), or all dependencies (which refer to props or state). (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) So that would look like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    onScroll();
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    };
  }, [onsScroll]);
```

But that means I have to use `useCallback` for `onScroll` or it will always have a different depenedency. But the `useCallback` "dependency" for `onScroll` would be `window.pageYOffset`, but that doesn't work, i.e.:

```
function onScroll = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 0) {
      setFoor(bar)
    } else {
      setFoor(baz)
    }
  }, [window.pageYOffset])
```

My general question, is how do you deal with `useEffect`/`useCallback` functions that had outside dependencies? (Besides ignore the warning.)

Thanks

I also tried moving `onScroll` definition entirely inside the `useEffect` but it doesn't update properly.

```
useEffect(() => {
    function onScroll() {
      if (window.pageYOffset > 0 && !slim) {
        setSlim(true);
      } else {
        setSlim(false);
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll, onScrollOptions);
    onScroll();
    getAccountAction();
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll, onScrollOptions);
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies should be props or state, here you have a class method defined as a dependency, in your case I suppose you want to mount the event listener with a effect similar to componentDidMount, you can achieve that by setting an empty array as a dependency. In this case this is not wrong as the logic in the effect doesn't use any variables in the component scope.

In the event handler I would change state by setting the value of the pageoffset and in the other effect use that state as the dependency

Comment: > Dependencies should be props or state

OK, but sometimes effects call external libraries and stuff, this can't be included in the dependency but it's part of the effect

Answer (score 0):

Even if you define scroll handler inside `useEffect`, you're still accessing the offset from outside, which you need to track inside the dependencies array as well as the `slim` state var.

Your onScroll function can be simplified by using functional form of `setState`, in which case you won't need to track `slim` state variable anymore:

```
useEffect(() => {
  function onScroll() {
    setSlim(currentSlim => window.pageYOffset > 0 && !currentSlim)
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll, onScrollOptions);
  getAccountAction();
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll, onScrollOptions);
  };
}, [window.pageYOffset]);
```